# Numerical Solution of 1D Boltzmann Transport Equation

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, numerical-method

I need to solve the one-dimensional Boltzmann transport equation in a semiconductor numerically, and I want to take a deterministic approach toward the problem (i.e. not use Monte-Carlo or similar non-deterministic methods).

Do you know any good reference (preferably a book) to help me in this regard?

Comment: Did you try your favorite search engine? When I searched for [Boltzmann transport equation in a semiconductor numerically](https://www.google.com/search?q=Boltzmann+transport+equation+in+a+semiconductor+numerically) by copy-pasting from your question, lots of links pop up quickly (your question is first of course). [This paper](https://math.la.asu.edu/~chris/ttsp02.pdf) presents a deterministic approach but it's not a book and I don't know if it's particularly a good reference, it's the first I found though.

Comment: Also -- what kind of background do you have in numerical methods? Are you looking for an intro book, or something very specific to this topic, or something else?

Comment: I am looking for an introductory book on deterministic simulation of 1D Boltzmann transport equation for electron transport in semiconductors. As you mentioned, there are lots of references available. But since I am new to this field, most of them are beyond my current understanding of the subject. I was hoping to find somebody who has done similar projects and knows the best way to approach this specific problem.

Comment: I guess my question is more about your general background. If I told you that the Boltzmann transport equation is hyperbolic, do you know what that means numerically? Do you instantly have an idea in mind of what can be used to solve it? I would be surprised if you found a book that shows you how to solve this particular problem numerically. You'll find books that tell you how to solve general classifications of problems like hyperbolic PDE's, and then you'll find papers specific to your particular equation that tells you how to compute individual terms.

Comment: I do not have a strong background in numerical simulation of PDEs. In the past year, I have numerically solved the 3D Poisson equation, 2D Schrodinger equation and also drift-diffusion equation in a semiconductor device. But I do not know about the different classifications of numerical problems, and have been able to solve the above mentioned problems by reading and learning specifically about the problem at hand. I also do not know what a hyperbolic PDE means (I knew about these classifications in my B.Sc. years, but I have forgotten them over the years!).

Comment: @tpg2114, could you please share some materials about the meaning of hyperbolic BTE with me? I'm studying the paper you shared 8 years ago. I already looked up several papers about it, but still don't quite understand what that means numerically. All I know is somehow it guarantees the existence and the stability of BTE solutions. My background is physics and electronics, but just a little bit numerical simulation.